# What could cause a 30 k g acceleration?

Tags: acceleration

I'm reading the specs of an IC (Cypress 5LP SoC) and it says it's available in 30 k g shock resistance configuration. The fastest acceleration I heard of so far was hitting a golf ball hard, which would be around 1000 g. Does anyone have an example of a mechanical impact of 30 000 g (300 000 m$\cdot$s$^2$), applicable to electronics devices?

Comment: I've always loved the _Orders of magnitude_ articles on wikipedia.  There is one for [acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(acceleration)) too

Comment: @StevenVH - you might find this interesting: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/is-there-a-maximum-possible-acceleration

Comment: I am guessing that the manufacturer has a test rig that can go up to 30 k g... in fact, there [is an article here](http://www.empf.org/empfasis/june05/g0605.htm) describing several such methods including a drop test that produces 30k g. The key is to make the impact "short" (30 s drop, 1 ms stop = 30 k g if $F\Delta t$ is to be believed. With a "shock amplifier", the drop can be less).

Answer (score 4):

I've always loved the *Orders of magnitude* articles on wikipedia.  They list examples for the whole range of magnitudes for many physical quantities.  There is one for [acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28acceleration%29) too.

Among them:  Rating of electronics built into military artillery shells: 15 500 G