# Is acceleration continuous?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, mathematics

The extrapolation of this Phys.SE [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291886/).

It's obvious to me that velocity can't be discontinuous, as nothing can have infinite acceleration.

And it seems pretty likely that acceleration can't be discontinuous either - that jerk must also be finite.
All 4 fundamental forces are functions of distance so as the thing exerting the force approaches, the acceleration must gradually increase (even if that approach/increase is at an atomic, or sub-atomic level)
e.g. in a Newton's Cradle, the acceleration is still electro magnetic repulsion to it's a function of distance, so it's not changing instantaneously, however much we perceive the contact to be instantaneous. (Even if we ignored the non-rigidity of objects.)

Equally I suspect that a force can't truly "appear" at a fixed level. Suppose you switch on an electromagnet, if you take the scale down far enough, does the strength of the EM field "build up" from 0 to (not-0) continuously? or does it appear at the expected force?

---

Assuming I'm right, and acceleration is continuous, then jump straight to the infinite level of extrapolation ...

Is motion mathematically smooth?

Smooth: [Smoothness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness): Being infinitely differentiable at all point.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151399/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1324/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score -2):

Not a physicist, but I think acceleration can be discontinuous. Consider a car travelling at constant velocity (acceleration = 0) that hits a wall. De-acceleration (negative acceleration) commences until the car comes to a complete stop. For all intents and purposes over time t acceleration starts at zero, decreases to a negative value (because de-acceleration), and then instantaneously jumps back to zero.

My 2 cents.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. It's great to see new faces here, but I'm afraid this answer is just completely wrong. A car colliding with a wall doesn't start decellerating instantaneously. Apart from anything else "a car" isn't a thing with a single velocity or acceleration! And see my original question for arguments about why even a body that does appear to be close to an inelastic collision still isn't truely experiencing discontinuous acceleration.

Answer (score -2):

With respect, I  think you're splitting hairs.

Before the wall, the velocity is constant, and a = 0. After the wall, the velocity is constant at 0, and a = 0. In between velocity is decreasing to 0, acceleration is the derivative of the velocity as a function of time, at some non-constant value of un-changing sign (since it's either constantly decelerating, or accelerating), so how does it start at 0, end at 0, and have some value of unchanging sign in-between without being discontinuous?

Comment: Please don't post two answers like this. Fix your previous answer & delete this one. Or vice versa. ;)

Comment: On what grounds are you asserting that it's constantly decelerating?

Comment: I get it, thanks. I was assuming the acceleration graph was directional, downward slope deceleration, upward slope acceleration. (I don't know why I was assuming that). No, it's just an initial large amount of deceleration, then deceleration of lesser magnitude returning to zero. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

acceleration cannot be infinite.  Things need a force to be able to accelerate an object. So to infinitely accelerate and object it needs a infinite force. Also try wording question  better.