# Is there a limit to $\frac{d^nx}{dt^n}$?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration, jerk

There is already a question on the limit of acceleration($\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$) and we all know the limit of velocity($\frac{dx}{dt}$) which is $c$ or the speed of light.

My question is a generalized version of the previous questions.

Is there a limit to $\frac{d^n x}{dt^n}$? And if there is a limit then what is the general formula based on the physical constants to calculate the limit of $\frac{d^n x}{dt^n}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upper limits for jerk and higher derivatives in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/476491/)

Comment: What do you mean that order n derivative does not have any meaning?Order 1 or velocity means the change of position ,Order 2 or acceleration means the increasing or decreasing of velocity, order 3 or jerk means increasing or decreasing of acceleration, order 4 means increasing or decreasing of jerk and so on.

Comment: I said order $n \gt 3$ but I think my comment got deleted when the question was closed. What order is $n\gt 3$? I know about velocity, acceleration, jerk lol.

Comment: In order to define order n>3 you need to use your own new word, that doesn't mean that it makes order greater than 3 have any less physical significance