# Is there an upper bound on acceleration?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, acceleration

We know from the Theory of Relativity that there is an upper bound on velocity, namely the speed of light $c=2.99792458\cdot 10^8\frac{m}{s}$. Is there an analogous upper bound on acceleration? I don't think there is an upper bound, and it can be as large as possible, but is it really true that there is no upper bound? If it is true, then what is the largest acceleration that can realistically happen (on Earth and in the universe)? Of course the speed of light puts a limit on how long any such acceleration can last (I haven't studied relativity yet, so if this statement is wrong, correct me), but how large can the instantaneous acceleration be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a maximum possible acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3334/)